# Combined search in dataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

i have a column where each row has either  'passed', 'failed' or 'ignored' as text . i want to do a filter search so only 'failed' and 'ignored' are visible. But I can't combine a search string within the same column. 'failed ignored' gives 0 results.

Any suggestions?

I use the dataTables jQuery plugin.

```
$('.tablesorter-js').dataTables();
```

And the html

```
<table class="tablesorter-js">
<thead>
<th>first column</th>
<th>second column</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>result</td>
<td>passed</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>result</td>
<td>ignored</td>
</tr>
</tbody
</table>
```

Comment: Any code to show what you have tried? That might give us some context as the question is a little vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out: this line does the trick.

```
var columnNr = 1
oTable.fnFilterAll((Pass)|(Ignored), 1, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that Datatables already does the kind of search/filtering you want, as you can see from the examples on their website.

However, there's a plugin that enhances column filtering on the [datatables site](https://www.datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColumnFilterWidgets/DataTables/extras/ColumnFilterWidgets/). It's called ColumnFilterWidgets and it allows you to choose several options from a dropdown (although you have to choose one at a time, but it remembers the ones you've already selected).

Comment: I tried experementing with http://datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColumnFilterWidgets/DataTables/extras/ColumnFilterWidgets/

But how do i make it work with multiple tables and fnFilterAll()? Spend all day trying to figure this out. I really could use some help : (

Comment: You mean using multiple tables on the same page? If you elaborate a bit I may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it's that you want but you can simply

#### HTML

```
<input id="search" value="" />
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // it's just an example 
    oTable = $('#example').datatable();
    oTable2 = $('#example2').datatable();
    oTable3 = $('#example').datatable();

    $('#search').on('keyup',function(){
           var value = this.value;
           oTable.fnFilter(value);
           oTable2.fnFilter(value);
           oTable3.fnFilter(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but im using multiple tables rendered as one datatable.